# use strict and gulp

Tags: javascript, plugins, gulp, strict

I want to add `'use strict';` to the top of my JS files. I have a lot files from different folders, that are merged into one file by concat. But some of them are jquery files, so adding `'use strict';` isn't needed. My task looks like this:

```
gulp.task(command, function () {
    gulp.src(path) // array of diff files
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat(outfile))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps', {
        sourceMappingURL: function(file) {
            return mappingURL + file.relative + '.map';
        }}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(BUILD));
});
```

I didn't use any tools like browserify or webpack. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You want to concatenate and minimize your app files and then concatenate JQuery with the result without minimizing it. Is that right?

Comment: Yup, something like:  concatFiles.js => wrap('strict mode') => concat with jQuery

Comment: Hm look like some of jQuery files not minimized, so it should be minimized too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using the `addsrc` and the `wrapper` plugins.

```
gulp.task(command, function () {
    gulp.src('some/src/...')
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      // Minimize your app files.
      .pipe(uglify())
      // Add Jquery to the beginning.
      .pipe(addsrc.prepend('jquery/path...'))
      // Concat all files.
      .pipe(concat('some-file'))
      // Add the "use strict" header.
      .pipe(wrapper({ header: '"use strict";\n' }))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('some-file', {}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('some/path/...'));
});
```

- `addsrc` comes from https://github.com/urish/gulp-add-src
- `wrapper` comes from https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-wrapper

**Not tested.

Comment: The problem that jQuery already have 'use strict' detective, so it should be excluded from wrapping. Also I do know why but in your solution jQuery files doesn't minimified

Comment: So jQuery have to be minified? Then I don't see your problem? If jQuery has "use strict" just concatenate all your files at the end of jQuery and minimize the result.

Comment: jQuery has modular structure so it wrapped inside iife so "use strict" doesn't have global effect. And I trying to do the same with other code.

Comment: Wrapping your code around a iife and add the 'use strict' is not a gulp thing in my opinion. You should do it in all your js files. So you can use your files separately and in bundle.